# Casting Pointer to Pointer

Tags: c++11

I have

```
void func(int ** Data, int x, int y);

short MAT[ROW][COL];
short *PP[ROW];

for (int k = 0; k < ROW; k++)
    PP[k] = &MAT[0][0] + COL * k;

func(reinterpret_cast<int **> (PP), ROW, COL);
```

Although it compiles, the results are not correct for Data.

Is it possible to cast from a pointer to pointer to short to another pointer to pointer to int.  If so then, how to get the correct casting for PP

Thanks

Comment: short is 2 bytes, while int is 4 bytes in size. Probably, that's the reason why you are not getting correct results? You are trying to take the address of a short array and trying to cast it into a pointer to an int array.

Comment: @niting, Yes I know that. I want to see if possible to cast from pointer to pointer to short  to another pointer to pointer to int.

Comment: There are many many things wrong in this code. Isn't it assuming ROW == COL  or ROW >= COL? `func` I am assuming is reading invalid memory region based on how an array of short is being converted to integer.  Can you tell us what exactly are you trying to do ? Maybe we can suggest you safer alternatives.